# std::function<> and the Intel compiler version 11.1

Tags: c++, lambda, intel

I'm having trouble working with lambda functions in the Intel compiler, in particular, the following code won't compile:

```
template<typename T>
std::function<T (int)>  make_func(T x) {
  return [=](int index) -> T
  {
     return x;
  };
}
```

The error I get is

```
error: namespace "std" has no member "function"
```

The code compiles and runs fine on my Mac, (macports gcc version 4.5). The error is at work, where we use the Intel compiler version 11.1. It does accept lambda functions (with the -std=c++0x option), such as:

```
auto lam = [=](int j) -> int {
    printf("testing for lambdas: %d\t%d\n", n, j);
    return n;
};

int g = lam(7);
```

The version of gcc installed at work is 4.1.2, so I'm guessing that the standard library is old?

```
/bin/libc.so.6
```

says it's version 2.5 compiled with gcc 4.1.2.

Is there a way around this?

thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Did you include `<functional>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get the same behavior with icc 11.1 on a system where gcc 4.5.2 is installed.

`g++`'s header `<functional>` is protected with `#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__` which is not defined when `icc` is used.

I would consider switching to [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html) in this setup, which of course works with icc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would simply #define __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__, before #include<functional> get the desired result? I'll try it when I get back to work tomorrow. I'd prefer to stay away from boost for this particular project. Thanks again.

Comment: @nmaxwell I tried that, and icc choked on varadic templates found all over the place in gcc 4.5.2's libraries. I don't know if your gcc 4.1.2 headers have those. On the other hand, boost's function.hpp is a header-only library, which could be added without a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the code shown doesn't include *a single* header. And yet you refer to the standard library `std::function`.

So no, it doesn't compile. As with any other part of the standard library, you need to include the header where `std::function` is defined: `<functional>`.

Comment: Sorry, it was a snippet, the headers I included are "#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> "

Comment: Thanks,
I just assumed that function would be in header 'function'. Coding java and kotlin has just made me assume stuff like that =)